# Can I return a cached Observable from switchMap without using state external to the RxJS pipeline?

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I would like to create an RxJS pipeline that only switches to a new Observable (firing an API call) when the pipeline parameter has changed. However, **I still want the most recent value re-emitted** whenever a new parameter comes through.

So far, I've constructed the following pipeline that does more or less what I want:

```js
const { fromEvent, scan, map, startWith, pairwise, switchMap, tap, of, shareReplay, delay } = rxjs;

const events = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4];

let cache$;

fromEvent(document, 'click')
  .pipe(
    scan((count) => count + 1, -1),
    map((count) => events[count % events.length]),
    startWith(undefined),
    pairwise(),
    switchMap(([prev, curr]) => {
      if (prev === curr) {
        return cache$;
      }

      cache$ = of(curr).pipe(
        tap((val) => console.log(`New subscription for ${val}`)),
        delay(1000), // See edit to original question
        shareReplay(1)
      );

      return cache$;
    })
  )
  .subscribe((val) => console.log(`Received ${val}`));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/7.8.1/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
<div>Click anywhere and watch the console output</div>
```

Note that a new inner pipeline is only created when a distinct/changed value is observed in the parent pipeline, but every value in the parent pipeline results in some output arriving at the `subscribe`.

This code works decently, but **I'm disappointed in the use of "external" state** via the `cache$` variable. I would much prefer a solution that keeps all the logic entirely within the pipeline, for readability and "purer" code.

**Is it possible to achieve the result demonstrated above, without any external state tracking?**

### Edit: Long-Running Inner Pipeline

@akotech provided a [great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76416201/2977638) using `switchScan` that answered the question almost perfectly. However, my original example above did not explicitly simulate the effect of a *long-running inner pipeline* (where the response from "the API" is delayed). When adding a `delay`, the `switchMap` above still produces the right response once it is received (no matter how many clicks occur), and caches it for any subsequent returns. Using `switchScan`, however, runs the risk of losing the subscription to the long-running observable *before it returns a value*, leaving the cache in a stale or indeterminate state.

**Is there a solution that produces consistent results, even with delayed inner-observable return values?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could a `scan` operator to cache the observable and later switch on it using `switchAll`.

```
 ...,
 scan(
   (cached, [prev, curr]) =>
     prev === curr
       ? cached
       : of(`${curr}":Result`).pipe(
           tap((val) => console.log(`New subscription for ${val}`)),
           delay(1000),
           shareReplay(1)
         ),
   EMPTY
 ),
 switchAll()
 ...
```

**EDIT:** originally proposed `switchScan` but that option would only work for sync internal observables.

Comment: This solution is so close to what I need! In testing though, I realized that this solution yields slightly different results _in the case where the inner pipeline is delayed_. For both, add a `delay(1000)` immediately after the `tap`. Click several times within one second. For `switchMap`, the result is logged (and cached) as soon as the original pipeline returns. For `switchScan`, the inner pipeline is abandoned, and `undefined` is returned until a new param comes through. Do you have any thoughts about that case? I'll update the question accordingly, but I greatly appreciate your answer!

Comment: I'm also more than happy to mark your answer as accepted if nothing else comes up: you definitely answered the original question as I had written it. I'll add another answer here if I can find any workaround to the `delay` issue I described in the edited question.

Comment: @RNanoware my bad. For async internal observables you cant use `switchScan`since that would cached the result emitted and not the observable. But you can achieve the functionality just splitting the `switchScan` into a `scan` (to cache the observable) + `switchAll`( to switch on them).

Comment: @RNanoware Well, I see you already found the solution while I was posting :)

Comment: No worries, your solution is even better with the built-in `switchAll`! I will mark your answer as accepted. Thank you so much for your fast response!

Answer (score 0):

@akotech's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76416201/2977638) got me 90% of the way there, but I realized I needed something that could handle long-running (delayed) inner pipelines. The solution I currently have uses a combination of `scan` to generate the inner pipeline (cached with `shareReplay`) and then `switchMap` to "fold" those inner pipelines back into the top level.

Here's a snippet demonstrating the setup:

```js
const {
  fromEvent,
  scan,
  map,
  startWith,
  pairwise,
  switchMap,
  tap,
  of ,
  shareReplay,
  delay,
  EMPTY
} = rxjs;

const events = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4];

fromEvent(document, 'click')
  .pipe(
    scan((count) => count + 1, -1),
    map((count) => events[count % events.length]),
    startWith(undefined),
    pairwise(),
    scan((cache$, [prev, curr]) => {
      return prev === curr ?
        cache$ :
        of(curr).pipe(
          tap((val) => console.log(`New subscription for ${val}`)),
          delay(1000), // Simulating a slow response
          shareReplay(1)
        );
    }, EMPTY),
    switchMap((cache$) => cache$)
  )
  .subscribe((val) => console.log(`Received ${val}`));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/7.8.1/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
<div>Click anywhere and watch the console output</div>
```